# mapreduce spill in not getting finished and reducer stuck for second job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, chaining

I am trying to run two chained mapreduce jobs in Ubuntu single node cluster in Pseudo- distributed mode. First job got finished successfully and got the desired result. And while the second job is running, it is showing "Starting flush of map output" message for two times.then map task getting stated, showed 100% reduce 0%. And the spill is not being finished also.total task got stuck at this point.

### console log where second job got stuck:

```
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local1934661043_0002
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1934661043_0002_m_000000_0
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@e1ef17
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/mahesh/outpu/part-r-00000:0+51
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
14/12/18 17:29:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
14/12/18 17:29:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/12/18 17:29:10 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
14/12/18 17:29:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

### Find the Driver Class to check how the jobs are configured:

```
public class NetflixAvgRatingSorted extends Configured implements Tool{


     private static final String OUTPUT_PATH = "/user/mahesh/outpu";

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
          /*
           * Job 1
           */
          Configuration conf = getConf();

          FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
          Job job = new Job(conf, "NetflixAvgRating");
          job.setJarByClass(NetflixAvgRatingSorted.class);

          job.setMapperClass(NetflixAvgRatingMap.class);
          job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
          job.setReducerClass(NetflixAvgRatingReducer.class);

          job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
          job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);

         /* job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
          job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);*/

          FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(OUTPUT_PATH));

          job.waitForCompletion(true);

          /*
           * Job 2
           */
          Configuration conf2 = getConf();

          Job job2 = new Job(conf2, "NetflixAvgRatingSorted");
          job2.setJarByClass(NetflixAvgRatingSorted.class);

          job2.setMapperClass(NetflixAvgRatingSortedMapper.class);
          job2.setReducerClass(NetflixAvgRatingSortedReducer.class);

          job2.setOutputKeyClass(CompositekeyWritable.class);
          job2.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
          job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(CompositekeyWritable.class);
          job2.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

          /*job2.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
          job2.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);*/

          FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path(OUTPUT_PATH+"/part-r-00000"));
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));

          return job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
         }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (args.length != 2) {
           System.err.println("Enter valid number of arguments <Inputdirectory>  <Outputlocation>");
           System.exit(0);
          }
          ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new NetflixAvgRatingSorted(), args);
         }

}
```

please notify if anyone found the mistake in configuration settings or related things. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone could please provide update on this.